# MySQLi Table Exists

Tags: php, mysqli

In PHP, what would be the best way of seeing if a table exists?

This is what I am using so far

```
public function TableExists($table) {
    $res = $this->Query("SELECT 1 FROM $table");

    if(isset($res->num_rows)) {
        return $res->num_rows > 0 ? true : false;
    } else return false;
}
```

Comment: I would `SHOW TABLES` and search the results for your table name. The above is going to throw an error.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What you posted is going to throw an error if the table doesn't exist. Try this instead:

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE 'tablename';
```

And ensure that you get exactly one row back.

Comment: Alright thanks. That works great. Thanks everyone else for the answers

Comment: well this didnt work for me it still echo does not exist in mysqli_query()

Comment: What if the table exists but it doesn't have any rows? Your approach doesn't work in this case

Comment: This query is not impacted by the number of rows in the table. It will return a result whether the table has rows or not.

Answer (score 13):

Colin has the right solution -- to use `SHOW TABLES LIKE`. Here is what it would look like using your code:

```
public function TableExists($table) {
  $res = $this->Query("SHOW TABLES LIKE $table");
  return mysql_num_rows($res) > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For seeing, if `[table name]` exist

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_schema = '[database name]' 
AND table_name = '[table name]';
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the `SHOW TABLES` approach from other answers is using the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_database_name' AND TABLE_NAME = 'tablename';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$con = mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$database);

if(mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con,"SHOW TABLES LIKE 'accman'"))) {
  echo "DB EXIST";
} else {
  echo "DB Not Exist";
}
```